# "Merge" solutions of diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

$$13x + 12 = 22y + 19 = 20z + 3$$

---

I am able to solve the first **diophantine equation** $13x + 12 = 22y + 19$ in the classic form of $ax + by = c$ like $$13x_1 - 22y_1 = 7.$$
In this case the condition of existing solution is met: $gcd(a, b) | c \rightarrow gcd(13, -22) | 7$. The solution is $x_1 = -35 + 22n, y_1 = -21 + 13n$.

I am also able to solve the equations:

- $13x_2 + 12 = 20z_1 + 3$. The solution is $x_2 = 27 + 20n, z_1 = 18 + 13n$.
- $22y_2 + 19 = 20z_2 + 3$. The solution is $y_2 = -8 + 10n, z_2 = -8 + 11n$.

Based on that, it is possible to "merge" solutions $x_1 = -35 + 22n$ and $x_2 = 27 + 20n$ into $x$ that fullfils the original equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. If we get $z_1=z_2$ then it will apply $$13x_2+12=20z_1+3\ \ and \ \ 22y_2+19=20z_1+3$$
which is equivalent to your equation.
Solution to $z_1=z_2$ is
$$18+13n=-8+11k$$
$$n=-2+11m,\  k=13m$$
Where  $n$ is parameter in solution of first and $k$ parameter in solution of second equation.
Now substituting these into equations for $x_2,y_2,z_2$ we get:

- $x_2=-13+220m$
- $y_2=-8+130m$
- $z_2=-8+143m$

which solves your equation.

Comment: Is it possible aply this approach for more equations? For example: $13x + 12 = 22y + 19 = 20z + 3 = 31u + 12$, I am only interested in the variable $x$, respectively all results of $13x + 12$.

Comment: It is possible, you only have to solve $13x+12=31u+12$ to get $(x_3,u_3)$ then set $x_3$ and $x_2$ equal. This will yield solution to new equation